# OnActivityResult Doesn't work with activityGroup

Tags: android, activitygroup, start-activity

im my App i use TabHost. and ActivityGroup to load activities under the tab. on my 2nd tab i open activityGroup "TabGroupActivity"... and from here i open a child activity "childActivity2". from the "childActivity2" i want to open an normal activity which has a theme dialog. and when i return from my normal activity i want to run the onActivityResult() in my childActivity2. 
But the onActivityResult() in ChildActivity2 is not working.

the code where in childActivity2 to start the normal activity is

```
data.putInt("doctorId", doctor_id);
                Intent createSchedule = new Intent(ScheduleWeekly.this, CreateSchedule.class).putExtras(data);


                startActivityForResult(createSchedule, 1);
```

this is my onActivityResult()

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {   Log.e("get","result");
            .................
                         ......
        }


    }
```

Comment: You should use custom Listner to come out of this

Comment: how we can do that.... any sample code???

Comment: i didnt get your idea... can u give me any sample codes...

Comment: instead of onActivityResult() i use onResume method and write the code 
inside the onResume()... is it a rightway???

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is same as mine. The problem is that the onActivityResult function won't directly trigger from a child activity in activity group, even your intent is from that child activity.

The solution is divided in three steps.

First, you have to let your parent activity, that is your ActiviyGroup class to call the startActivityForResult function in the position you need to jump out the current activity. In your child activity, when you need to lunch your normal activity, instead call:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

You should call:

```
getParent().startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

This will let the ActivityGroup to take care of the call back. In your case, since your have three level nested, you may have to try whether the parent or grandparent should take care of the call back and make proper modification about getParent() part.

Second, after you make the parent class of current activity start the intent, you will need to add onAcivityResult() function into BOTH parent class and the current child class. In current class you just write normal call back handle message as you do now. But in parent class, the onActivityResult() function will catch the call back from the normal activity and deliver the intent to the current class.

Third, This step is for the parent onActivityResult class, in that class, your need:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, data);
    switch (resultcode)
    {
    case RESULT_OK:
         MyChildActivity CA = (MyChildActivity) getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
         CA.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, data);
    } 
}
```

As you can see, the onActivityResult function in parent ActivityGroup class is just catch the call back, get the child activity you which needs to jump to another activity, and transfer the data to it. You may not need exactly onActivityResult function in your child activity as state in Step 2, but I think this is a better way to do it.

Hope this help!